# Deploying Moodle Docker

Tags: php, docker, curl, moodle

I'm using [moodle-docker](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-docker) and trying to run it on a cloud VPS (virtual private server), I've bought a domain and link it to the public ip address provided by the VPS.

I've cloned a [Moodle](https://github.com/moodle/moodle) repository in the VPS and set up the moodle-docker to point to it like so

```
export MOODLE_DOCKER_WWWROOT=~/Sources/moodle &&
export MOODLE_DOCKER_DB=mysql &&
export MOODLE_DOCKER_WEB_HOST=my-domain.my.id &&
export MOODLE_DOCKER_WEB_PORT=8000
```

but when I open `my-domain.my.id:8000` it give me error `Connection refused`. I also tried to use `curl` even from inside the VPS itself, here is the command:

```
curl -v -g 'http://my-domain.my.id:8000'
```

the result:

```
*   Trying 103.170.85.180:8000...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 103.170.85.180 port 8000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to my-domain.my.id port 8000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to my-domain.my.id port 8000: Connection refused
```

I also tried to run a custom web server on it to make sure that I can access it from the internet. The web server run on port 8085, and i can `curl` it just fine:

```
curl -v -g 'http://my-domain.my.id:8085/ping'
```

```
*   Trying 103.170.85.180:8085...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my-domain.my.id (103.170.85.180) port 8085 (#0)
> GET /ping HTTP/1.1
> Host: my-domain.my.id:8085
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 54
< ETag: W/"36-wY0ccM5thB7kDQk7rQPWw2Kfc/Y"
< Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2022 03:45:35 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< 
* Connection #0 to host my-domain.my.id left intact
{"status":"running","time":"2022-07-11T03:45:35.204Z"}
```

I've been tinkering for a few days with no result so if you have anything that i could try feel free to comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checking the list of running docker I noticed the ports on the web server that can be accesed is using `0.0.0.0:8085->8085/tcp` and the moodle-docker is using `127.0.0.1:8000->80/tcp`. I read the [moodle-docker-compose](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-docker/blob/master/bin/moodle-docker-compose) and it's using `127.0.0.1` if bind ip is not specified.

So changing from

```
export MOODLE_DOCKER_WEB_PORT=8000
```

to

```
export MOODLE_DOCKER_WEB_PORT=0.0.0.0:8000
```

works for me but I'm not sure why. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: moodle-docker is meant to be a quick and easy development environment, not a full production environment.
The default port binding (127.0.0.1:8000) means that moodle-docker is only listening on port 8000 for connections where the destination IP is the loopback address (127.0.0.1). This is a security feature to prevent external access to your dev environment.
The binding you've set (0.0.0.0:8000) means that moodle-docker will listen on port 8000 regardless of the destination IP